# Uri nula al eliminar y volver a guardar un Layout como imagen Android

Tags: java, android, imagen, bitmap, uri

Estoy tratando de guardar toda el contenido de una pantalla en formato imagen, para ello en mi `layout` tengo un `LinearLayout` en donde se van agregando todos los demás elementos.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/creado"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Luego, este mismo es creado:

```
private LinearLayout contenido;
```

Y llamado en el método `onCreate()`:

```
contenido = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.creado);
```

Para almacenar todo el contenido del `Layout`, uso el evento `setOnLongClickListener`

```
        contenido.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                if(permissionHelper.hasPermission()){
                    GuardarLayout(VistaPrevia.this);
                }else{
                    ejecutar();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Para guardarlo hago los siguientes métodos:

```
private void GuardarLayout(Context context){
    contenido.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    contenido.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bmap = contenido.getDrawingCache();
    try {
        guardarImagen(bmap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } finally {
        contenido.destroyDrawingCache();
    }
}

private void guardarImagen(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
        ContentValues values = contentValues();
        String filePath = "Pictures/" + "Genshin Impact Mis Builds";
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);
        Uri uri = this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        if (uri != null) {
            try {
                guardarImagenParaStream(bitmap, this.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri));
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, false);
                Log.d("TRYURINONULL", "guardarImagen: " + uri);
                Toast.makeText(this, "¡Se ha guardado tu build de manera exitosa!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("CATCHURINONULL", "guardarImagen: " + uri);
            }
        }else{
            Log.d("URINULA", "guardarImagen: " + uri);
        }
    } else {
        File directorioRuta = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + '/' + getString(R.string.app_name));
        if (!directorioRuta.exists()) {
            directorioRuta.mkdirs();
        }
        String nombreDelArchivo = nombrePersonaje + ".jpg";
        File archivoFinal = new File(directorioRuta, nombreDelArchivo);
        try {
            guardarImagenParaStream(bitmap, new FileOutputStream(archivoFinal));
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, archivoFinal.getAbsolutePath());
            this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

private ContentValues contentValues() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, nombrePersonaje + ".jpg");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/*");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    return values;
}

private void guardarImagenParaStream(Bitmap bitmap, OutputStream outputStream) {
    if (outputStream != null) {
        try {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

He instalado el aplicativo y noté lo siguiente, primero me deja almacenar el `Layout` n veces siempre y cuando no borre el archivo imagen desde su respectiva carpeta. Es decir, borrar su archivo yendo a la ruta manualmente y borrarlo. Al hacer eso, (eliminar el archivo imagen de manera manual y volverlo a guardar), probé debuggeando y obtuve esto:

Primero guardamos el archivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto nos da el siguiente logd:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Corroboramos que se haya almacenado en la carpeta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, borramos el archivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Volvemos a la App e intentamos guardarlo de nuevo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El `logd` nos da esto (uri nula):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y, claramente, no se ha guardado nada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por qué la `Uri` se vuelve nula después de borrar el archivo manualmente? ¿Qué estoy escribiendo mal en el código? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Desde ya, muchas gracias

**DESCRIPCIÓN**

El problema radica en la siguiente acción. Cuando guardo el archivo por primera vez, puedo guardarlo reiteradas veces (esto va generando algo como **archivo1.jpg, archivo2.jpg**) pero cuando me dirijo a su respectiva carpeta (actualmente `Pictures/Genshin Impact Mis Builds`) y borro dichos archivos, al momento de querer guardar el archivo otra vez es cuando la `uri` adquiere el valor `null`. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar eso?

Comment: Excelente, voy a revisar lo que comentas, a primera vista veo que usas Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() que es obsoleto y estas usando targetSdkVersion 29 :-< voy revisar Franqo!

Comment: Sí, eso es porque si el sdk es < 29 usará el enviroment y si es mayor o igual usará el mediastore para almacenar @Jorgesys

Comment: Ok, estuve tratando de ver como cargabas VistaPrevia veo que si guarda la Imagen pero el problema como mencionas es que no obtiene la URI, voy a agregar una respuesta , dame unas horas!

Comment: Estaba tratando de ver como carga VistaPrevia, ya veo como funciona y que es el problema, voy a agregar una repuesta màs tarde, solo que me llamo la atenciòn, esta linea: uri = resolver.insert(contentUri, contentValues); no existe en VistaPrevia.java

Comment: No me están llegando las notificaciones, pero lo que me dices con respecto a esa línea que no está, muy probablemente se deba a que he estado cambiando el código varias veces y ya no debe estar. La imagen quedó en base a la referencia de la nulidad de la Uri al momento de eliminar la imagen y volver a guardarla, la actualizaré luego para que no se preste a confusiones @Jorgesys

Comment: Mañana voy a probar en un dispositivo 10 y 11, tal vez tenga que ver con el sistema operativo, solo quiero afirmar, el problema es que al eliminar la imagen la uri siempre devuelve null y si creas el archivo ahí vuelve a dar null el valor de la URI ?

Comment: Guardas el archivo, lo borras, intentas guardar el archivo otra vez y la uri se vuelve null

Comment: Me parece que lo que ocurre es porque no has notificado el borrado del archivo, al parecer eso debe hacerse mediante `MediaScanner` Intenta hacer [algo como esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64936194/5587982). Quizá haya algún modo más sofisticado de asignar un Observer o algo así a la carpeta para que notifique los borrados manuales cuando ocurran. Creo que por ahí está el asunto...

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo he visto cual es el problema, no tiene que ver con el sistema operativo, cambia tu código y valida que cree y busque pero evitando usar "/sdcard/Pictures/", lo que sucede es que seguramente creaste la imagen en otra ubicación y al revisar después de eliminar la imagen te indica que aún existe, revisa mi respuesta, si tienes duda mañana edito el código, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el path es incorrecto al ver tu còdigo la imagen se tratarìa de guardar en la siguiente ruta que es incorrecta:

```
relative_path Pictures/Genshin Impact Mis Builds [Imagen].jpg
```

Se puede ver en los valores definidos para el guardado de la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, nombrePersonaje + ".jpg");
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
Uri uri = this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Aquì si obtendràs un valor al obtener la Uri:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Actualizaciòn:**

Pensaba que el problema se debería a el sistema operativo pero no hay ningún problema, el problema se debe en realidad a las rutas que usas para guardar los archivos,  comentas que el problema radica en que cuando eliminas el archivo no puedes volver a guardarlo.

Revisando a detalle encontré el problema, creas un archivo y verificas si este existe mediante:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures"
```

pero posteriormente usas como ruta donde se crearía el archivo:

```
"/sdcard/Pictures/"
```

**No debes definir el path mediante  "/sdcard/Pictures/" ya que la ruta puede ser diferente en los dispositivos, seguramente tu aplicación guardo una imagen en otra ubicación y al validar ya no permite crear una nueva aunque no exista en la ubicación que deseas**, esto sucede en este método:

```
private void saveImagesTwo(Bitmap bitmap){
    File ruta = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures");
    if (!ruta.exists()) {
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Pictures/");
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    File archivo = new File("/sdcard/Pictures/", nombrePersonaje + ".jpg");
    if (archivo.exists()) {
        archivo.delete();
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(archivo);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "¡Se ha guardado con éxito tu build!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("saveImagesTwo", "try: " + "\nRuta: " + ruta + "\nArchivo: " + archivo);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "¡Ha ocurrido un error al intentar guardar tu build!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("saveImagesTwo", "Catch: " + e.getMessage() + "\nRuta: " + ruta + "\nArchivo: " + archivo);
    }
}
```

de hecho usando `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures"` se obtiene la ruta :

```
 /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Barbara.jpg
```

pero usando `/sdcard/Pictures/` se obtiene otra ruta de archivo diferente:

```
 `/sdcard/Pictures/Barbara.jpg`
```

Debes usar solo una clase para almacenar y verificar la existencía de tu archivo, en el caso de tu aplicación usa `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures"`

Comment: Si, entiendo lo que dices pero el problema persiste. Verás, el problema está en que cuando borras el archivo no puedes volver a guardarlo. Haz esto, guarda el archivo, ve a la ruta donde se guarda y borralo. Vuelve a la app e intenta guardarlo de nuevo...

Comment: Ok Franqo dejame revisar, creo saber que sucede! :D

Comment: Vale, he actualizado la pregunta con gifs que muestran lo que trato de decir :D

Comment: Pues, no, no me ha funcionado... Me sigue saliendo null la Uri luego de borrarlo y tratar de guardarlo otra vez. Otra cosa, ¿Dónde estas asignando el path? No lo veo en tu actualización...

Comment: Franqo, que sistema operativo usas?

Comment: **SO: MIUI Global 12.0.1** Android 10 Q, Xiaomi Redmi Note 7

Comment: Ha sido un golazo, mil gracias !

Comment: Que bien que se pudo solucionar el problema, saludos !

Answer (score 1):

Es `null` porque estás usando un `MediaStore.DownloadColumns.RELATIVE_PATH` sin checar el `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`. Encontré este [gist](https://gist.github.com/samkirton/0242ba81d7ca00b475b9) que funciona ala perfección.

```
/**
 * Android internals have been modified to store images in the media folder with
 * the correct date meta data
 * @author samuelkirton
 */
public class CapturePhotoUtils {

    /**
     * A copy of the Android internals  insertImage method, this method populates the
     * meta data with DATE_ADDED and DATE_TAKEN. This fixes a common problem where media
     * that is inserted manually gets saved at the end of the gallery (because date is not populated).
     * @see android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media#insertImage(ContentResolver, Bitmap, String, String)
     */
    public static final String insertImage(@Nullable  ContentResolver cr,
                                           Bitmap source,
                                           String title,
                                           String description) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, title);
        values.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, title);
        values.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, description);
        values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        // Add the date meta data to ensure the image is added at the front of the gallery
        values.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
        values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());

        Uri url = null;
        String stringUrl = null;    /* value to be returned */

        try {
            url = cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

            if (source != null) {
                try (OutputStream imageOut = cr.openOutputStream(url)) {
                    source.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, imageOut);
                }

                long id = ContentUris.parseId(url);
                // Wait until MINI_KIND thumbnail is generated.
                Bitmap miniThumb = Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, id, Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, null);
                // This is for backward compatibility.
                storeThumbnail(cr, miniThumb, id, 50F, 50F,Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
            } else {
                cr.delete(url, null, null);
                url = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (url != null) {
                cr.delete(url, null, null);
                url = null;
            }
        }

        if (url != null) {
            stringUrl = url.toString();
        }

        return stringUrl;
    }

    /**
     * A copy of the Android internals StoreThumbnail method, it used with the insertImage to
     * populate the android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media#insertImage with all the correct
     * meta data. The StoreThumbnail method is private so it must be duplicated here.
     * @see android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media (StoreThumbnail private method)
     */
    private static final Bitmap storeThumbnail(
            ContentResolver cr,
            Bitmap source,
            long id,
            float width,
            float height,
            int kind) {

        // create the matrix to scale it
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

        float scaleX = width / source.getWidth();
        float scaleY = height / source.getHeight();

        matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY);

        Bitmap thumb = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0,
                source.getWidth(),
                source.getHeight(), matrix,
                true
        );

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
        values.put(Images.Thumbnails.KIND,kind);
        values.put(Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID,(int)id);
        values.put(Images.Thumbnails.HEIGHT,thumb.getHeight());
        values.put(Images.Thumbnails.WIDTH,thumb.getWidth());

        Uri url = cr.insert(Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        try {
            OutputStream thumbOut = cr.openOutputStream(url);
            thumb.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, thumbOut);
            thumbOut.close();
            return thumb;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            return null;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Tu `GuardarLayout` sería:

```
private void GuardarLayout() {
   try {
       Bitmap bmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(contenido.getMeasuredWidth(), contenido.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
       Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmap);
       contenido.draw(canvas);
       String filename = System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
       CapturePhotoUtils.insertImage(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), bmap, filename, "description");
   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: Pues, no guarda nada. No lanza ningún problema, pero no almacena la imagen.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta por si quieres pegarle una ojeada

Comment: Vale que raro, porqué a mí si me guarda la imagen en el folder de "Pictures". Posiblemente si abres el album las podrás ver. Usé ese código sin el `storeThumbnail` y la imagen se guardó hasta el último.

Comment: He actualizado mi pregunta, he modificado mi código y el problema está en que cuando me dirijo a la carpeta donde se guarda el archivo y lo elimino, al volver a la app y guardarlo otra vez es cuando la uri se torna null. ¿Sabes como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Tal como indica la documentacion de ContentProvider cuando haces un `insert`:

> Implement this to handle requests to insert a new row. As a courtesy, call [notifyChange()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#notifyChange(android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver)) after inserting. This method can be called from multiple threads, as described in Processes and Threads.

Intenta llamar al método `notifyChange(uri, null)` luego de la inserción de los archivos.
Para evitar temas de `Context` y/o fallos con el ciclo de vida, usa `ApplicationContext` en vez de `Context` de tu actividad para ejecutar la acción de guardar la imagen. Puede ser que el problema este relacionado al contexto y un problema de sincronización. Puedes verificar esto, corriendo la siguiente secuencia:

1. Agregar las imágenes.
2. Borrar una o varias imágenes de manera manual tal como indicas en tu escenario.
3. Agregar nuevamente la o las imagenes. Si el Uri te devuelve `null`, entonces procede con el paso 4.
4. Cerrar el app y volver a abrirla e intentar insertar las imagenes de nuevo. Si te deja guardarlas y no te devuelve Uri `null`, el problema puede estar relacionado al Contexto, por lo tanto intenta usar `ApplicationContext` para obtener la instancia del `ContentProvider`.

Puedes reviar la [documentacion oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics) para verificar que todo esta en orden.
Te dejo un ejemplo [gist](https://gist.github.com/andrespengineer/a0d2a873977d9e175ba4a8e49bb14d25) que cree, déjame saber si te funciona.

Comment: Estuve intentando lo que mencionas pero obtengo lo siguiente: `Cannot resolve method 'notifyChanges' in 'ContentResolver'` en la siguiente línea: `resolver.notifyChanges(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri), null);`

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo intenta con `notifyChange`, quitale la `s`, ya que estaba escrito como `notifyChanges`...

Comment: Bien, hice como mencionas. Seguí los primeros tres pasos lo que me llevó al 4to, hice lo que mencionas y el resultado sigue siendo el mismo. Luego de eliminar las imágenes, ya no puedo volver a guardarlas. (Incluso, como dices, probé cerrando y abriendo de nuevo la app)